# Alamofire: Create array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, alamofire

The JSON that needs to be sent to the server is this:

```
[
    {
        "value": "0",
        "optionId": "de07a0ae-9b85-4f2a-bd8f-28f0ccb55f81"
    },
    {
        "value": "1",
        "optionId": "abe075ef-d76e-45e0-ace9-e73218604b87"
    },
    {
        "value": "0",
        "optionId": "820124a6-a6ed-499e-8d0d-7ac04160f56d"
    },
    {
        "value": "0",
        "optionId": "0d8cb27a-2659-4e54-a4f0-0b0a10131da5"
    }
]
```

So I created an array of Dictionaries:

```
var parameters = [[String:NSObject]]()
```

But Alamofire is only accepting a dictionary. Is there a way to do the JSON encoding by myself an pass it to Alamofire as an parameter? Or how would you solve it?

> Cannot convert value of type '[[String : NSObject]]' to expected
>   argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to send it like this by serialising the array to json.

```
var parameters = [[String:AnyObject]]()
if let url = NSURL(string:urlString){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: [])

            Alamofire.request(request)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .Success(let responseObject):
                        print(responseObject)
                    case .Failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: Using Alamofire 4.x, NSMutableURLRequest can't be cast to URLRequestConvertible. According to the documentation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#urlrequestconvertible, the "request" variable should be of type URLRequest. With that small change this solution works great.